# How to display in a console values from SQL Server using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, console-application

I have a simple SQL Server database table `Persons` (`PersonID, Name, Age` - 4 rows). I want to display this value in a console app using Entity Framework Core.

My class:

```
class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    private const string stringConnection = @"Server=localhost; Database=Persons; Trusted_Connection=True;";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(stringConnection);
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Table `Persons`:

[image: Persons]

What code should I write to display these values in a console app?

Comment: Show us **YOUR** efforts so far! Where are you stuck? We'll help - but not just write the whole code for you ....

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your `AppDbContext` to your repository, businesslogic, or controller, or where you want to the query

after that you can do something like:

```
AppDbContext _context;
public YourClassName(AppDbContext context)
{
 _context = context;
}
public object YourMethod()
{
var result = _context.YourTable.ToList();
return result;
}
```

And you'll get as result a list the T is the entity class generated by entityframework